# Using Dijsktra's algorithm with unique distance between nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, path-finding

For a school project, my friends and I are learning what is pathfinding and how to exploit it via a simple exercise:

For a group of ants going from A to B, they need to travel through multiple nodes, one at a time.

I've read some explanation about Dijsktra's algoritm, and I wanted to know if I could use it in a graph where every distance between every node is 1 unit. Is it optimal ? Or is A* more appropriated to my case ?

EDIT:

Since I had knowledge on the graph, BFS was prefered because distance between node was pre-computed, where Djisktra is prefered when you have absolutely nothing about the graph itself. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374357/why-use-dijkstras-algorithm-instead-of-best-cheapest-first-search) for reference

Comment: *"Is it optimal?"* That is relative. We cannot answer that. But if you are learning, then Dijsktra is something that is easy to start with.

Comment: easy was the word, thanks for having my back.

Comment: Dijkstra is a special case of AStar. You can find an explanation on SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16268762/5847906

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://ai.stackexchange.com/ or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. Also there are plenty of similar questions already asked and there are plenty of online resources discussing these algorithms. Take a look at [ask] and [mcve] before you post a question a Stack Overflow, it's important to do some research yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every edge has the same cost, then Dijkstra's algorithm is the same as a breadth-first search.  In this case you might as well just implement BFS.  It's easier.

If you have a way to estimate how far a point is from the target, then you could use A* instead.  This will find the best path faster in most cases.

Comment: DFS is not about shortest distance. You mean BFS, right?